# Group values from a 3d array into an associative 2d array and sum values with a shared path

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum, grouping

I have already seen [this
stackoverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827501/php-how-to-sum-and-group-by-a-multidimensional-array-by-a-key) but it is not helping me.

I want to group by two columns and sum the values of a third column.

If the `discount_id` and `dis_percent` are the same then add the `discount_value`.

Here is my array:

```
$dis = [
    [['Dis_id' => 'Dl-Dis1'], ['Dis_per' => '7.500'], ['Dis_val' => '192.75']],
    [['Dis_id' => 'Dl-Dis2'], ['Dis_per' => '2.500'], ['Dis_val' => '97.88']],
    [['Dis_id' => 'Dl-Dis1'], ['Dis_per' => '5.000'], ['Dis_val' => '39.90']],
    [['Dis_id' => 'Dl-Dis2'], ['Dis_per' => '2.500'], ['Dis_val' => '99.90']]
];
```

The output that I need is:

```
D1-Dis1->7.5->192.75
D1-Dis1->5.0->39.9
D1-Dis2->2.5->197.78
```

My code looks like this:

```
$newarr = array();
$reverse_map = array();

foreach($dis as $idx => $entry) {
    if (isset($reverse_map[$entry['Dis_id']])) {
         // have we seen this name before? retrieve its original index value
         $idx = $reverse_map[$entry['Dis_id']]; 
    } else {
         // nope, new name, so store its index value
         $reverse_map[$entry['Dis_id']] = $idx;
    }

    // copy the 'constant' values
    $newarr[$idx]['Dis_id'] = $entry['Dis_id'];
    $newarr[$idx]['Dis_per'] = $entry['Dis_per'];

    // sum the qtd_post values to whatever we previously stored.        
    foreach($entry['Dis_val'] as $x => $y) {
        $newarr[$idx]['Dis_val'][$x] += $y;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the dis_id and dis_per are what? Also, have you got any examples of code where you've tried to solve this so we can see where you are having issues?

Comment: dis_id is the name and dis_per is the percentage for the dis_id. i gave the amt and the result after deduct from the dicount percent is dis_val.. please see the code i tried

Comment: "a condition if the discount_id and dis_percent are then add the discount_value" <- if they are what? You haven't said what the condition is

Comment: sql query can do it. You need to provide it

Comment: condition is array 0 dis_id is equal to array 1 dis_id and array 0 dis_per is equal to array 1 dis_per and so on. if the condition is true then sum the array 0 dis_val with array 1 dis_val.. the same for all the array values. can u understand

Comment: @raheel i want it in the php no query

Comment: Right.. So I'm getting the idea that you want to sum up the `Dis_val` for all entries, grouped by `Dis_id` and `Dis_per`. I've written a solution, but also noticed that your array structure is quite odd, and doesn't match how your attempted solution works. Is it intentional that each entry contains a subarray, in which there is just a single element for either `Dis_id`, `Dis_per` or `Dis_val`? Hopefully you'll get what I mean by this; http://pastebin.com/FDjVWy6z

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I've come up with based off of the understanding that your intended array structure was as so;

```
$dis = array(
    array(
        'Dis_id'  => 'Dl-Dis1',
        'Dis_per' => 7.500,
        'Dis_val' => 192.75
    ),
    ...
);
```

It determines the solution by creating a multidimensional array where the first dimension is the `Dis_id`, and the second dimension is the `Dis_per`, and the value becomes the sum of the `Dis_val`;

```
$sums = array();

foreach ($dis as $entry) {
    if (!isset($sums[$entry['Dis_id']])) {
        $sums[$entry['Dis_id']] = array();
    }
    if (!isset($sums[$entry['Dis_id']]["{$entry['Dis_per']}"])) {
        $sums[$entry['Dis_id']]["{$entry['Dis_per']}"] = 0;
    }
    $sums[$entry['Dis_id']]["{$entry['Dis_per']}"] += $entry['Dis_val'];
}
```

See this working example; https://eval.in/158661

Answer (score 0):

As you iterate your input array, use array destructuring to isolate the `Dis_id` and `Dis_per` values and use them as keys when storing your `Dis_val`.

If the key path hasn't been encountered before, default the stored amount to 0 and add the current amount to it.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NlpBl))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($dis as [['Dis_id' => $id], ['Dis_per' => $per], ['Dis_val' => $val]]) {
    $result[$id][$per] = ($result[$id][$per] ?? 0) + $val;
}
var_export($result);
```